# iOS code signing as a company not as an individual

Tags: ios, code-signing

I am working at a research center and they asked me how to sign code as a company (rather than as an individual developer).

I have been googling for a while but I haven't found out anything regarding how to do so. I have been looking through [apple's documentation too](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html) but still nothing. Does anybody here knows how to proceed in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [sign up your company for an Apple Developer account](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/), separately from your personal one.

They don't make it clear (at least in the pages that I just scanned), but I believe the company version of the Apple Developer account allows multiple team members.

There's some more [useful information at the Developer Account FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference when it comes to code-signing.  You generate the key pair the same way, you generate the certificate signing request the same way, you create app IDs the same way, you create provisioning profiles the same way, you compile the code the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apple Developer Account needs to be setup as a company, rather than individual. Code signing has nothing to with wether or not your account is setup as a company or not.

When you setup your Developer Account, you need to input what you want to display as the seller name, and you are not able to change this once it is setup, and the process should explain that to you.

I also don't think there is a way to switch over to a company account if you have already setup your developer account as individual, but you can always call Developer Support to see if it can be changed over.